# Replacement for deprecated PostgresDataType.JSON?

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I'm using JOOQ with PostgreSQL, and trying to implement a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO dest_table (id,name,custom_data)
SELECT key as id,
       nameproperty as name,
       CONCAT('{"propertyA": "',property_a,'", "propertyB": "',property_b,'","propertyC": "',property_c,'"}')::json as custom_data
FROM source_table
```

The concatenation/JSON bit is what I'm here to ask about. I actually have managed to get it working, but only by using this (Kotlin):

```
val concatBits = mutableListOf<Field<Any>>()
... build up various bits of the concatenation ...
val concatField = concat(*(concatBits.toTypedArray())).cast(PostgresDataType.JSON)
```

It concerns me that `PostgresDataType` is deprecated. The documentation says I should use `SQLDataType` instead, but it has no `JSON` value.

What's the recommended way to do this?

EDIT: a bit more information ...

I'm building the query like this:

```
val innerSelectFields = listOf(
    field("key").`as`(DEST_TABLE.ID),
    field("nameproperty").`as`(DEST_TABLE.NAME),
    concatField.`as`(DEST_TABLE.CUSTOM_DATA)
)

val innerSelect = dslContext
    .select(innerSelectFields)
    .from(table("source_table"))

val insertInto = dslContext
    .insertInto(DEST_TABLE)
    .select(innerSelect)
```

The initial query I posted is slightly misleading, as the resulting SQL from this code doesn't have the 
`(id,name,custom_data)` part.

Also, in case it matters, "source_table" is a temporary table, created during runtime, so there are no autogenerated classes for it.

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ currently doesn't support the JSON data type out of the box. The main reason is that it is unclear what Java type to bind a JSON data structure to, as the JDK doesn't have such a standard type, and jOOQ will not prefer one third party library over the other.

The currently recommended approach is to create your own custom data type binding for your preferred third party JSON library:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings

In that case, you will no longer need to explicitly cast your bind variable to some JSON type, because your binding will take care of that transparently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it appears that the "custom_data" field already DOES have a JSON binding defined (public final TableField<DocumentRecord, JsonNode> CUSTOM_DATA = createField("custom_data", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.OTHER, this, "", new JsonNodeBinding())), and yet without the cast(), I get the error 'column "custom_data" is of type json but expression is of type text'. I've updated my initial question with some more information.

Comment: @StevenFrew: I think your updated question is no longer the same question as the original one. As there will be many people visiting this question in the future, would you mind creating a new question with your update? I think that will be less confusing for future visitors.

Comment: Reposted as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852602/alternative-for-deprecated-cast-to-postgresdatatype-json